# Unable to Sign in with google

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have to add sign in with google feature to my app. I have tried several tutorials but nothing works. Whenever I select an account from the list, that pop up gets closed and nothing happens. I don't know what is the problem since there is no errors showing on the logcat.

Login.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;    
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;      
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity  {

    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    RelativeLayout googlesignin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

        googlesignin = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.googlesignin);
        googlesignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 101);

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 101) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Homewindow.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User Logged In Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

activity_login

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginmain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/logincontents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/relativelayout_custom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/googlesignin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/loginlayout">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/googleicon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/googleicon"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/googletext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/googleicon"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/averia_gruesa_libre"
                    android:text="Sign in with Google"
                    android:textColor="#db3236"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/facebooksignin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/googlesignin"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/loginlayout">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/facebookicon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebookicon"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/facebooktext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/averia_gruesa_libre"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/facebookicon"
                    android:text="Sign in with Facebook"
                    android:textColor="#3b5998"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/skipbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/facebooksignin"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/averia_gruesa_libre"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="SKIP NOW >>"
                android:textColor="#00BFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileicon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/logincontents">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_icon"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I used onClickListener for the Relative layout containing googleicon and text.

build.gradle (app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            applicationId "com.example.parethumukal"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

// ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation files('libs\\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.0'


    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

logcat error

```
07-23 21:48:22.994 21934-21934/com.example.parethumukal E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

07-23 21:48:27.924 21934-21982/com.example.parethumukal E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb37a4d60
```

I don't know if any errors with my codes. Codes are taken from firebase site.

Comment: Can you please show your logs, so it is very easy to detect

Comment: added some errors shown in logcat.. pls check

Comment: Have you enabled Google sign in firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.firebase_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .enableAutoManage(this, null)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this dependency:

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'**

Comment: Oh my bad. Any way have you added firebase service json file?

Comment: He already implemented that i think that's why he can manage to do other stuff.